# How to add a binding to an existing web site in Plesk

Tags: iis, plesk

I've created a website in Plesk, and in my DNS records, I've added a record that resolved to the IP of the server which hosts Plesk and website.

Now I want to add that IP to the bindings of website in IIS. How can I do it through Plesk?

Answer (score 1):

Plesk automatically bind your site to IP address.

You just need to create site on this IP in plesk or change it in Hosting Settings.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I fail to understand how it solves my problem. I don't want to create a site, because I've already done it. Now the problem is about automation, that is, I have a procedure that creates sites, creates DNS records, and then I need to be able to bind those records to the created sites programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Plesk offers domain aliases. Domain aliases allow you to point several domain names to the same (existing) website.

Go to Websites & Domains and run the Add Domain Alias wizard.

If you don't want redirection to the main domain make sure you disable the 301 redirection.

More information can be found at: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/websites-and-domains/domains-and-dns/adding-domain-aliases.65286/